# how to update custom library in different project?

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I have two projects, pro1 and pro2

pro2 setup.py:

```
setup(
    name='pro2',
    url='http://local_gitlab/username/pro2.git',
    author='me',
    author_email='myEmail@hgf.com',
    version='0.2',
    license='MIT',
    long_description=open('README.MD').read(),
    description='description',


    packages=find_packages(),

    install_requires=['pandas', 'numpy'],
    package_data={
            '': ['*.txt', '*.rst'],
        }
)
```

in pro1 requirements I have installed pro2, pro1 requirments.txt:

```
git+http://local_gitlab_server/username/pro2.git
```

Now, when I commit and push new feature into pro2,

How can I update pro1 venv to get pro2 new feature?

Comment: Maybe update the version?

Answer (score 0):

First, increase `version` in `setup.py`:

```
version='0.2.1',  # just an example
```

Second, declare the version in dependencies in `pro1`:

```
git+http://local_gitlab_server/username/pro2.git#egg=pro2-0.2.1
```

This way `pip` will see the new version even before cloning the repo.